# Inaccessible BIOS since debian installation

Tags: boot, debian, bios

I own an Acer swift 5 on which I wanted to install debian 9. Since its installation, it is impossible for me to access the BIOS: indeed if I press the F2 button at startup, I only have a black screen.

My grub starts correctly but does not allow me to access the bios either.
The problem seems to be a recurring one on this machine, but no one seems to have found a solution.

If someone could find a way to fix this problem, you'd save my life.

Comment: These two statements aren't connected. Installing debian wouldn't of stopped you getting into the bios. The bios starts *before* grub, therefore I am guessing you maybe pressing the wrong key, or not fast enough.

Comment: @djsmiley2k There was a lot of motherboards which checks HDD for partition structure and hangs the boot process at all or displays error message (now I don't remember) when this structure was "unknown" to BIOS procedure. Maybe the author have something similar...

Comment: @Bast Try to disconnect HDD, then boot and try enter BIOS, if success, edit CMOS settings, then save and reconnect HDD.